# Typescript infer type parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to restrict the type of one object property based on value of another property:

```
type DataType = "string"|"number"|"date";

type DataTypeMapping = {
    "string": string;
    "number": number;
    "date": string;
}

interface LinkedTypesSample <T extends DataType> {
    typ: T;
    value: DataTypeMapping[T];
}
```

now I can create type checked objects like so:

```
const stringInstance: LinkedTypesSample<"string"> = {
    typ: "string",
    value: "abc"
}

const numberInstance: LinkedTypesSample<"number"> = {
    typ: "number",
    value: 1
}
```

The question is - is it possible to skip type parameter of `LinkedTypesSample`?
Looks like type parameter might be inferred from `typ`.

I tried to specify(naively) default type parameter like so:

```
interface LinkedTypesSample <T extends DataType = DataType> {
    typ: T;
    value: DataTypeMapping[T];
}
```

but in this case type checks stop work.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UBEBnYAnASwDsBzTAH0yIFcBbAIwjwswBMEJMBuAKB9EiwEyVAFk4YMMRJQMAbx5QlWXIVKYAXFFXTeyrDQZNNUQ4zx7lbDiZ2leAXz7FgTAGZwAxtAAyxANYQrCiQ2ADKcLRgADbQADxIUBAAHq5ErNhCiCEQAHxQCvoCWkiWSgBucNHUEFrw2WISUqQA2kgAuo58ngD2RLja%20NIAkv2IRN5afkSBwajhkTEQcThD6vnyisrFKmtkADRbFVU1Wphw9J6YPE48vWOmdOajuHATtVDTszkLUbErZmMGwKRygOyoT2Mh30lWqHwAjDdun0BoC8KM3Ew8EEXuNJp8AkEfhE-ugQUVwGc0ZhocpYacoIiHEA)

**Edit**: Ideally, I don't want 'LinkedTypesSample' to expose type parameter at all. I just want to express simple thought: one property must have certain type according to value or type of another property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types). Basically create the type in two steps:

```
type MapType<U> = U extends DataType ? {
    typ: U,
    value: DataTypeMapping[U]
 } : never;

type LinkedTypesSample = MapType<DataType>;

// works
const stringInstance: LinkedTypesSample = {
    typ: "string",
    value: "abc"
}

const numberInstance: LinkedTypesSample = {
    typ: "number",
    value: 1
}

// error
const stringInstance2:  LinkedTypesSample = {
    typ: 'string',
    value: 1
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UBEBnYAnASwDsBzTAH0yIFcBbAIwjwswBMEJMBuAKB9EiwEyVAFk4YMMRJQMAbx5QlWXIVKYAXFFXTeyrDQZNNUQ4zx7lbDiZ2leAXz4Do4sCkgAeAKoA+WVDeUBAAHsAQRKzYQoge0AD8UAr6AlreADSKygBucAA21BBa8LFiElKkANreALqKDlBaRBDZTLz8qFAAMsQA1hCscdgAynC0YHnoUG5xniUikL7tAMYA9kS42vjSAJIbiETLRd19A0Oj45MBycqpKtvqmfq5BceYcPTLmDxOPGv7pjo5j2uDgh2OPSI-UGqBGYwmUxuSjuVCBxieOXyhS0AEYfnx-ps7CQQQcjgAmLQnKFnWEXBHXLLI8BaADkxNZGKUL2xUDxDiAA).